# Appending to Variables

Tags: macros, errors

The following code works:

```
\def \robble {robble}
\def \robbles {\robble\robble}
```

But the following but doesn't:

```
\def \robbles {robble}
\def \robbles {\robbles robble}
```

The overall goal is to get `robbles` to be robblerobble. I need something like the second example, where I am appending on to the current value of a variable. The way it is written right now causes a stack overflow. Is there a way to append to variables in LaTeX?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to expand the `\robbles` macro in your second macro definition, otherwise you'll get a circular reference (`\robbles` calls `\robbles` which in turn calls `\robbles`). You can do that by saying

```
\def\robbles{robble}
\edef\robbles{\robbles robble}
```

where the `\edef` stands for `expanded definition`. This will expand the macros in the definition completely, until there's only unexpandable tokens left. That's fine in this case, because the contents of `\robbles` were only unexpandable tokens to begin with.

But if you initially defined `\robbles` to contain a macro, you would only want to expand `\robbles` once in the new definition. To do that, you can use `\unexpanded\expandafter{\robbles}` in the macro definition:

Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\robble{robble}
\def\robbles{\robble} % \robbles contains the macro \robble
\edef\robbles{\robbles robble}

\robbles    % Will print "robblerobble"

\def\robble{ROBBLE} % We're redefining the macro used in the original definition

\robbles % Will still print "robblerobble", because we completely expanded \robble in the definition of \robbles

% Let's try again

\def\robble{robble}
\def\robbles{\robble} % \robbles contains the macro \robble
\edef\robbles{\unexpanded\expandafter{\robbles}robble}

\robbles    % Will print "robblerobble"

\def\robble{ROBBLES} % We're redefining the macro used in the original definition

\robbles % Will print "ROBBLErobble", because we only expanded \robbles once in the definition of \robbles
\end{document}
```

Comment: Better use `\unexpanded\expandafter{\rubble}` than `\expandafter\noexpand\rubble` if eTeX is available (always). This covers the case where `\rubble` expands to more than just one macro.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Thanks, I've changed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

If it doesn't has to be local, you could use `\g@addto@macro` for appending to a macro:

```
\g@addto@macro\robbles{robble}
```

If necessary, use [`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) because of the `@` in the name.

Alternatively, you can append to a macro if you change the expansion order, it also works locally if grouped:

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\robbles\expandafter{\robbles robble}
```

`\expandafter` can reverse the expansion of two tokens. By using multiple `\expandafter` you can achieve here, that the second `\robbles` is expanded at first. Further explanation is given in [A tutorial on expandafter](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf) by Stephan v. Bechtolsheim in TUGboat 9-1.

Answer (score 0):

If we wish to expand completely the macro, then `\edef\mymacro{\mymacro,3}` works great as mentionned above.

But if you only want to expand once your macro, then I like `\expanded{…}` more and more (intuitively, it expands its parameter, except for tokens prefixed with `\noexpand`, and then it expands the resulting string). Since we want to postpone the evaluation of `\def` and `\mymacro`, we can simply prepend `\noexpand` in front of them:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\mymacro{1,2}

My macro is \mymacro

\expanded{\noexpand\def\noexpand\mymacro{\unexpanded\expandafter{\mymacro},3}}

My macro is \mymacro

\end{document}
```

Note that `\unexpanded\expandafter{…}` can be replaced with `\expandonce{…}` if we load etoolbox, since it actually expands only once the macro.
[image]