# How to make commands that gather arguments and place in later section?

Tags: macros

I'd like to roll my own commands that achieve something similar, in principle, to how [`\index`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing) places the indexed term in a later section, or how footnotes place text in a footer.

```
\summaryandextended{
    I'm just a summary of a result, and should appear in main text.
}
{
    I'm a long, complicated derivation of the result above. 

    I belong in the back portion of the book, read only by the nerdiest of nerds.
}

\gatheredappendix % I collect all of the #2 arguments and display them.
```

I don't want to duplicate either indexing or footnotes per se; I'm curious how one could make commands that build arbitrary collections of content within a specified section of a document.

Comment: You will use `\summaryandextended` multiple times, I assume?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, precisely.

Comment: You could use `tcolorbox` and it's `savelowerto` feature as well

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Interesting, thanks! In my immediate application that's likely the more expedient solution, though the `expl3` approach you gave was exactly the general approach I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a `expl3` syntax way: Store the second argument for later use on `seq` variable and display it later on with `\gatheredappendix`.

This way no external file is necessary (as would be for `\index`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}



\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_gather_stuff_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\storesecondarg}{+m}{%
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_gather_stuff_seq {#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\gatheredappendix}{}{%
  \seq_use:Nn \l_gather_stuff_seq {\par}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\summaryandextended}{+m+m}{%
  #1%
  \storesecondarg{#2}%
 }


\begin{document}

\summaryandextended{
    I'm just a summary of a result, and should appear in main text.
}
{
    I'm a long, complicated derivation of the result above. 

    I belong in the back portion of the book, read only by the nerdiest of nerds.
}

\summaryandextended{
  Other stuff
}
{
  Other useless stuff

  Even more useless text
}

\vskip\baselineskip
\hrule

\vskip\baselineskip

\gatheredappendix % I collect all of the #2 arguments and display them.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Christian, your response got me pointed in a fruitful direction. I didn't want to ask an elaborate follow-up question in comments, so I asked another [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276616/in-expl3-how-to-reset-a-seq-variable-when-content-is-placed-in-footer-or-fl).

Comment: The assignments should be global, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

This task is simply solvable by TeX primitives. You needn't any special package.

```
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\gatheredappendix{}
\long\def\summaryandextended#1#2{#1\global\addto\gatheredappendix{#2\par}}
```

Really, you need only these three lines (independent of used format). On the other hand, when `\usepackage{xparse}` is used then TeX needs to read 21711 lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing really complicated: it's a matter of augmenting the definition of a macro:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\summaryandextended}[2]{%
  #1% typeset the first argument
  \g@addto@macro\sean@extensions{\sean@extension{#2}}%
}
\gdef\sean@extensions{}% initialize

\newcommand{\gatheredappendix}{\sean@extensions}
\newcommand{\sean@extension}[1]{#1\par}% or whatever formatting you'd like
\makeatother
```

Note that, instead of just pushing the second argument in the replacement text of `\sean@extensions`, I add some structure making it the argument to `\sean@extension` that can then be used to specially format the texts. For instance, you may want to use an itemized list. In this case, change the definitions for `\gatheredappendix` and `\sean@extension` like

```
\newcommand{\gatheredappendix}{%
  \begin{itemize}
  \sean@extensions
  \end{itemize}
}
\newcommand{\sean@extension}[1]{\item #1}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

1. In your preamble, set `\gatheredappendix` to the empty string:

   ```
   \newcommand{\gatheredappendix}{}
   ```
2. Then define a command `\summaryandextended` with two arguments that does the following:

   a) Redefine `\gatheredappendix` by adding the second argument `#2` (see [Appending to Variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38200/appending-to-variables) or other places at tex.stackexchange)

   b) Output the first argument `#1`.

Of course, `\summaryandextended` could do additional things, like adding a new subsection title or so whenever content is added to `\gatheredappendix`.