# In expl3, how to reset a seq variable when content is placed in footer or float?

Tags: macros, expl3

This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276593/90325) explains how to use `expl3` to store a `seq` variable to place content later in a document. I'd like to write a command that:

- Writes the first argument to the main flow of the page.
- Writes the second argument to the contents of a floating element at the bottom of the page. (A `tcolorbox` box in this case, though not necessarily.) This argument will in practice only ever be a single sentence, and the command should concatenate them into a paragraph.
- Writes these only if there is room for both on the current page. If not, it should begin a new page with the first argument, and a new floating element at bottom, containing the second argument.

It may be that `expl3` is unnecessary here, in which case I welcome other approaches.

Comment: On first thought I don't find that `expl3` `seq` features are needed here. With `bottom` you mean the footer?

Comment: All is easy, but not the `keeping` on the same page ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, that's right. I avoided "footer" because I was unsure whether the term applied only to elements repeated over pages (numbering and the like). Keeping does seem to be the trouble. My brief read of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/90325) suggests that TeX's greedy float placement may pose an obstacle.

Comment: In my point of view, you don't need the floating at all. You want to have some text with `#1` and the second argument should be shifted to the footer. This isn't floating! Perhaps `savelowerto` is the better way.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I think you're right that the floating is rather unrelated. `\savelowerto` seems like the right idea. I think I'll dig through the source to see how to accomplish the same thing in my own commands.

Answer (score 2):

No full solution so far, only a test.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{myfooterbox}[1][]{
  colback=yellow!50!white,float,floatplacement={b},title={footer box \thetcbcounter},coltext=black,#1}


\NewDocumentCommand{\writemystuff}{O{}+m+m}{%
    #2
  \vfill %\push the box to the bottom
  \begin{myfooterbox}[#1]
    #3
  \end{myfooterbox}
}




\usepackage{blindtext}




\begin{document}

\writemystuff{\blindtext[3]}{\blindtext}


\writemystuff{\blindtext}{\blindtext}



\end{document}
```