# Automatic List of Corrections

Tags: automation

I have an edition of a document and I'd like to create a new edition with corrections on several places.

What's the best way to create a list of corrections?

I would imagine encapsulating the 'wrong' text with some command (e.g. `\wrong{ }`), and then encapsulating the corrected text by some other command (e.g. `\fixed{ }`).
Then I could (a) get a list of corrections automatically by the page and section of each correction, and (b) toggle the display of the corrected version.

Is there anything like that I can use?

Thanks.

EDIT: I used the post proposed in the comments and modified to make this:

EDIT 2: Following the responses I made this correct as well, for future use.
So this snippet now does what it should.

```
\documentclass{journal}

\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\correctionslist{}

\long\def\rightwrong#1#2{#1\edef\curpos{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}\expandafter\global\expandafter\addto\expandafter\correctionslist\expandafter{\curpos: RIGHT: #1\\ WRONG: #2  \par}}


\begin{document}
\newcommand{\curpos}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\section{How to make cookies}
\subsection{Why do we want cookies?}
Cookies are tasty.

\rightwrong{
    We like any type.
}
{
    But only if they're Oreos.
}
\subsection{How do we make them?}
We need flour and sugar.
\rightwrong{
    Some sugar will suffice.
}
{
    Lots of sugar.
}

\section{List of corrections}
\correctionslist 

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that `\curpos` is evaluated only when I call `\correctionslist`, so the section.subsection numbering is wrong. How can I solve this?

Thanks again.

Comment: You could look at the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276592/how-to-make-commands-that-gather-arguments-and-place-in-later-section/276594 and its answers.  The commands there also collect their arguments, print part of it, and print the rest later.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but in case you aren't aware... the latexdiff perl utility will read both tex files, typeset the entire document, highlighting the differences.  http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/latexdiff.html

Comment: You can use the [todonotes package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) to get colored margin notes, and also create a kind sort of *list of corrections* (list of todos) that you can create manually. In the section *1.8.13 Highligt text to fix*, page 18 you can find an idea for your `\wrong{}`command. And for `\fixed{}` you can create your own easily.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question - the solution is almost complete... I would appreciate any assistance in what's left to do.

Comment: Also related, my [`commenting`](https://github.com/bordaigorl/latex-commenting) package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to define `\curpos` inside `\rightwrong` by `\edef`.  `\edef` makes sure that all macros are expanded immediately, so the current position is indeed saved.  Also, one should add a few `\expandafter` to make sure that `\curpos` is expanded when `\rightwrong` is called.

```
\long\def\rightwrong#1#2{#1\edef\curpos{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}\expandafter\global\expandafter\addto\expandafter\correctionslist\expandafter{\curpos: RIGHT: #1\\ WRONG: #2  \par}}
```

There are some other things that should be done to make the output look nicer (e.g. separate different entries, add `\noindent`), but I guess the corresponding modifications should be "easy".

EDIT: added a few `\expandafter` to have `\curpos` directly evaluated when `\rightwrong` is called.

Comment: Thanks, but now it shows the section/subsection from the last call to ``rightwrong`` (in my example, both display "1.2").

Comment: Even if I add ``\edef\curpos{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}`` right before every call to ``rightwrong``, I get the correct result on Section 1 but then on the correction list itself I get the 1.2 number in both.

Comment: You are right. I was enthusiastic when I saw the "1.2", so I didn't realize that one of them should have been a "1.1".  I corrected my answer.